# Как удалить позицию из ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arrayadapter

Есть два фрагмента. В каждом ListView с адаптером. Адаптер представляет собой ArrayAdapter с LinkedList. На каждом из фрагментов список из объектов, часть из которых одинаковые. Удаляю позицию из первого фрагмента и хочу такую же удалить из второго при помощи метода `remove(MyObject object)`. В первом фрагменте удаление происходит, а во втором нет. Что я делаю не так и как удалить позицию из второго, не обновляя весь список (адаптер). Спасибо.

Comment: а код не приведете? Фрагменты на одном экране или это разные экраны?

Comment: @Pentiux, ViewPager на нем экземпляры одного фрагмента. На фрагментах ListView заполняемый через ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что бы выполнить метод `remove` необходимо в моем классе MyObject переопределить два метода `equals` и `hashCode`

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.id;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
        return false;
    MyObject my = (MyObject) obj;
    return (my.id == this.id);
}
```